# OOP splitting a class into creation and usage

Tags: oop, design-patterns, constructor

I'm using PHP if that matters and I keep track of the products with a class called Product.
The constructor accepts one parameter which is the id of the product. The constructor then goes to the database and gets all the information on the product and sets all the properties for that instance. Once all the operations are done, the user can call the save() function and the new information will update the product in the database

If the id of the product is set to zero in the constructor, then the product class understands that this is a new product and doesn't get any of the variables. It allows you to set all the variables and validates them. Then when you call the save() function it creates the product and sets the id of the product to the new id that was given to the row in the database.

The problem that I face is that certain functions cannot be called if the product is being created and wasn't saved yet because it doesn't have an ID. So at the moment every time a some functions are called I have to check that ID > 0.

I was wondering if it's a good idea to split the class into a class just for creation and a class for using an existing product (such as Product and CreateProduct). The benefits of this is that the Product class can always assume the product is already created so I don't have to check for that and all the validation methods can be moved to a separate class and better managed.

Just wanted to hear some opinions and any recommendations.
Thanks,
Alex

Comment: I think in other languages this would just be two different constructors, one that's supplied the ID and the other which isn't.

Comment: If you're sure the product instance will be saved somehow anyway, couldn't you reserve the ID in the database by inserting an empty row from within your constructor? Then in the "save" method you would actually do an db update, wether the product was newly created or not. This way any constructed product is assured to have an ID (which often is the use of a constructor = to obtain an object that is "safe" to use).

Comment: (Probably there is confusion between the software object, which is transient, and the database-resident "object", which is persistent.  The two are separate, physically and conceptually, though the software object is something of a "doppelganger" of the database-resident object.)

Comment: @darma - Among other possible reasons is the one that the new object may be "abandoned" before it's persistent identity is created, and one would not like to "waste" an ID on such a vaporous entity.  (I'm currently working on a project that is the, uh, doppelganger of Avovk's.)

Comment: Things that come to my mind reading this is "design by contract" and your new product could throw exceptions, which you could wrap behind a facade for products or whatever... but all depends on what you are trying to build (keep it simple). Nonetheless I think this is too much of a open ended discussion which is not what SO is made for... so this question will most probably be closed soon. Nevermind.

Comment: Yes migg has a point ; either your method cannot be called if ID=0 and therefore you should throw an exception, either it CAN be called and therefore you could implement an ID system for the "software" version of the product that doesnt yet exist in the db, like for instance a unique hash. And your code could work on those unique IDs only, except a DB access class that converts hashes from/to DB incremental IDs.

Answer (score 1):

In short yes, I believe so.  It sounds like the general behavior sounds like a candidate for the unsaved product to be a subclass of product, but this also depends heavily on whether a product regularly shifts from saved to unsaved over the execution of the script.  In which case you can remedy this by always having `$product->save()` return the correct object instance.

You can also benefit from this pattern in general since in the future if you add some sort of Product::find($id) method, you can then return a subclass that's more specific based on data that is loaded from the database, or in the case of 0, return a `CreateProduct`.

I'm of the school that initializing a class by a database ID is in general an awkward practice, and simultaneously creates branching logic for something that could be concrete. "Does the id exist? Do I throw an exception if the id doesn't exist?  Do I just set the id to null if it doesn't exist?"